# Enabling asp-prerender-module in ASP.NET CORE giving error

Tags: angular, asp.net-core

I'm getting this error on enabling asp-prerender-module in ASP.NET CORE:

> NodeInvocationException: Prerendering failed because of error:
>   TypeError: Cannot read property 'document' of undefined at
>   Rb.object.module.exports.module.exports at
>   Function.FusionChartsService.resolveFusionChartsCore  at
>   Function.FusionChartsModule.fcRoot

Answer (score 0):

The only solution I've reached is change your index.cshtml

```
<!--  remove this line
<app asp-prerender-module="ClientApp/dist/main-server">Loading...</app>
    -->
<!-- replace with -->
<app>Loading...</app>

<script src="~/dist/vendor.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>
@section scripts {
    <script src="~/dist/main-client.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>
}
```

Comment: Ya its working with this but i need asp-prerender-module so that server side rendering should work.Thats why i post this question

Answer (score 0):

In my case with ASP.NET Core 2 and Angular, this worked.

```
<app asp-ng2-prerender-module="ClientApp/dist/main-server">Loading...</app>
```